# FullCalendar dayClick fires on drag on iPad

Tags: fullcalendar

I have used the fantastic fullcalendar and added some touch and swipe type functionality for the iPad. I have a dialog that appears on dayClick which allows the user to add a new event and a similar dialog for eventClick in order that they can edit an event.

This all works fine but when I drag an event on the iPad/iPhone it also fires the dayClick event at the point that the drag started. So if I drag an event from say 2pm to 4pm then a dayClick event will also fire at 2pm.

This doesn't occur on the browser so I realise this isn't a bug I just wondered if anyone had any ideas on how to prevent this.

Many thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? It might help me for I cant drag and drop EXTERNAL objects to the calendar on the iPad. Will appreciate any help.

Comment: This might help you http://jsfiddle.net/veer712/KrZJr/17/